# Working with a PDF viewer plugin that is inside an iFrame element

Tags: iframe, cypress, pdf-viewer

Hope you are all right. I am stuck with a problem I can find a solution to. Maybe you will be able to help me here or give me some advice.

I need to download a PDF file from the website I'm working on. But this PDF is displayed as part of some PDF Viewer plugin that is attached to the application. And it's loaded to the page in the scope of IFrame.

It looks like this:

```
<iframe>
 #document
 <html>
  <body>
   <embed>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

So, no actual PDF viewer elements here. And when I try to click on the Download icon in this PDF Viewer, it opens another chrome-dev tools window with this element.

As I understood, this PDF Viewer is just "screwed into the page".

I have tried to use classic Cypress functions to work with shadow-dom and iframes, but they didn't help. I can't access the elements of this PDF Viewer plugin. Also, I was not able to find any info in google, cypress docs, etc ((

Maybe someone had a similar issue?

Anyway,

thanks in advance.